# How to run 2 async functions forever?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run 2 `async` functions forever. Can someone help me? My code and error message is provided below.

Code:

```py
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
import time

async def time(loop):
    while True:
        millis = await int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        print(millis)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)

async def stream(loop):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD') 
                    as websocket:
        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.recv()
                data = json.loads(data)
                print(data['data'][-1]['price'])
            except KeyError:
                pass
            except TypeError:
                pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(loop.run_until_complete(stream(loop)), 
                         loop.run_until_complete(time(loop)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

Comment: You were so close - just drop the `loop.run_until_complete`, and things should work fine. (Also, drop `await` before `int`, as pointed out in the answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are few errors with your snippet code:

1. You can't name your first function as `time` because it'll generate a conflict with `time` built-in function
2. Why are you passing `loop` as parameter if you're not gonna use it ? It's useless.
3. You can't `await` a function if it's not awaitable i.e. `int` is a synchronous built-in method.

Making the proper corrections it'll be something like this:

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
import time

async def another_name():
    while True:
        millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        print(millis)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)

async def stream():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD') 
                    as websocket:
        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.recv()
                data = json.loads(data)
                print(data['data'][-1]['price'])
            except KeyError:
                pass
            except TypeError:
                pass
            await asyncio.sleep(0.001) #Added

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coros = []
    coros.append(another_name())
    coros.append(stream())
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coros))
```

The line `await asyncio.sleep(0.001)` in `stream()` function is compulsory otherwise it won't never let the `another_name()` function runs.

Comment: You can’t `asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(...))`, so `main` does serve a purpose.

Comment: What's the point of the `coros` variable? `asyncio.gather` accepts awaitables positional arguments precisely so you can pass it a fixed number of arguments, as in `await asyncio.gather(one(), other())`, *without* going through the hassle of creating a list. Also, replacing `asyncio.run()`, which is the recommended way to run asyncio code, with `loop.run_until_complete()`, is somewhat of a downgrade.

Comment: You can improve the answer with your knowledge, we'll appreciate and learn from you

Comment: But then it would no longer be your answer, no? According to the description in the box, comments are "for suggesting improvements", which is how my comment is meant.